# How to I implement a trait on a builtin in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Rust :

```
let int: i32 = 3;
let float: f32 = 3.3;
let res = int*float; // Invalid
let res = (int as f32)*float; // Valid
```

To make this easier, I'm looking to implement an override on the `*` operator, which seems to be possible given Rust's error message :

```
cannot multiply `{integer}` by `{float}`
the trait `Mul<{float}>` is not implemented for `{integer}`
the following other types implement trait `Mul<Rhs>`:
```

But writing `impl Mul<i32> for f32` is apparently not possible either :

```
only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for primitive types
define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

So how is that supposed to be done ? Is there a crate already implementing those ?

Comment: It's simply not allowed by the compiler.

Comment: You cannot implement traits you don't own for types you don't own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't implement Mul for a primitive. This is part of rusts foreign type rules: For an implementation in your crate, at least one of the implemented type or trait must have been defined in your crate. Since neither Mul nor the primitive are defined in your code, you can't create an implementation for them.

If you really want to do this, you need to create a wrapper type around f32, and implement Mul and all the other relevant operators on that.